# Avoiding nested for loop without using array methods

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Say I have two arrays of objects. Like

```
var name = [
    { name : 'john' },
    { name : 'doe' }
]
var name2 = [
    { name : 'john' },
    { name : 'does' }
]
```

And I want to check if a name in the first array is the same as a name in the second array and return a response. I will do this below

```
for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < name2.length; j++) {
        if(name[i].name === name2[j].name) {
            console.log('good')
        } else {
            console.log('bad');
        }
    }
}
```

The above code would give the following result

```
good
bad 
bad
bad
```

How do I achieve the same result without using a nested for loop?

I tried using `forEach` to loop through at once. Like

```
name.forEach(function(value, index) {
    if(value.name === name2[index].name) {
        console.log('good');
    }
    console.log('bad')
});
```

But this doesn't work and gives issues when they are arrays of different lengths.

All my research lead to using `filter`, `map`, `reduce`... methods. I want to achieve this using just `for` loops only. Thanks.

Comment: Using example you made with `name` and `name2` variables, what is the exact output you want?

Comment: you have to use 2 loops in order to compare every element of an array with every other element

Comment: why not using nested loops? what other result do you expect?

Comment: @S.Orioli the same output in the question `good
bad 
bad
bad`

Comment: @NinaScholz same result but wihtout nested loops because of time complexity. The i have a time complexity of o(n^2). I feel there is a way to get at least o(n).

Comment: btw, what do you mean with ES6?

Comment: @NinaScholz no `filter` `map` `reduce` ...

Comment: ^^^ that is ES5. why do you think, a problem o(mn) can be moved to o(n)?

Comment: Okay but i don't wat to use any of those but just `for` loop

Comment: @WhiteHox `filter`, `map` and `reduce` are not ES6 features, they've been around for longer.

Comment: Do you just want to compare same indexes of 2 arrays? Or each index against every other index of the second array?

Comment: @VLAZ thanks. Now i understand that but i dont want to use any of those.

Comment: @adiga Yes exactly. The index values

Comment: @WhiteHox OK, I've edited the question to clarify that. But why do you want to avoid using array methods? Out of self-imposed challenge or some other restriction? Because it sounds quite strange.

Comment: @VLAZ it a restriction in a course im doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

> I tried using `forEach`. But this doesn't work and gives issues when they are arrays of different lengths.

I gather you want to compare both arrays irrespective of the length. So, you can get the maximum length out of 2 arrays using `Math.max`. Then, loop through and check if the 2 arrays have the same value at each index

The condition `name1[i] && name2[i]` checks for `undefined` when the smaller array doesn't have a value at the specified index.

```js
var name1 = [
    { name : 'john' },
    { name : 'doe' }
]
var name2 = [
    { name : 'john' },
    { name : 'does' },
    { name : 'jane' }
]

var maxLength = Math.max(name1.length, name2.length);

for (var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
  if (name1[i] && name2[i] && name1[i].name === name2[i].name)
    console.log("good")
  else
    console.log("bad")
}
```

Comment: It's also possible to use `Math.min`, assuming that it's OK to stop looping after the shortest array ends.

Comment: Hey, how can I handle the `out of range error` because the second list length is more than the first list length and the last `index` does not exist for the first list how can I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```js
var arr = [
    { name : 'john' },
    { name : 'doe' }
]
var arr2 = [
    { name : 'john' },
    { name : 'peter' },
    { name : 'doe' }
]

var i = 0, length = Math.min(arr.length, arr2.length);

for(i; i < length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].name === arr2[i].name) {
            console.log('good')
        } else {
            console.log('bad');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to have 2 loops. What you can do is the following: map that array into an object, have this structure for both arrays:

```
// first array
{
"jhon": 1, //count how many names u have in each array
"otherName": 1
}

// second array
{
"jhon": 1, //count how many names u have in each array
"otherName": 1
}
```

and then just compare those 2 arrays. Much faster and cleaner imo.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT You don't have for inside for, which is faster, maybe not for typing but performance wise (possibly). 1 function that accepts array, transforms it into an object. Maybe its not the best solution, but you pretty much wrote the same thing he did

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using "map" function in order to avoid using nested loops. Am not sure it answers the whole question but hope it helps.

```
//var search_value = 'john'; // will print 'good'
var search_value = 'doe'; // will print 'bad'

var name1 = [
    { name : 'john' },
    { name : 'doe' }
];

var name2 = [
    { name : 'john' },
    { name : 'does' }
];

var pos1 = name1.map(function(element) { return element.name; }).indexOf(search_value);
var pos2 = name2.map(function(element) { return element.name; }).indexOf(search_value);

var result = (pos1 == pos2) ? 'good' : 'bad';
console.log(result)
```